# Internet Speed for Webserver

Tags: windows-server-2008, web-server, internet, performance

That should be kind of dumb question in comparison to all other questions here.

**What minimum upload and download is required for a small home webserver with one webpage?**
Or is there a schema that shows me the required upload and download speed for a number of visitors?

We talk about a Windows Server, but not really sure this is relevant.

That's just for a practice project.

Answer (score 1):

That seriously depends. Practically "0" is pretty much the lower end - as in: whatever speed you have anyway is good enough for someone to watch occasionally, like you testing.

Especially if we talk "web page" as in "no videos, no large javascript" etc. - then an analogue modem would work good enough to test it.

Besides that, "it depends" pretty much is the only answer. Anything large? Programs, Videos - it gets high fast.

Comment: Ok, just say it's a small webpage for a really small company. Nothing special. Blogs, Images, maybe some youtube hosted videos.

What's about a shop? More visitors? Which up/down speed would be required?

(I just want scale it up here a little bit to see where the limit is)

Comment: Forget it. Seriously. Go hosting. Point. Then BANDWIDTH is not an isue at all - traffic mostly is (as in: servers are connnected with 100mb+ anyway - the question is more how much you use). Normally, upstream (FROM the server) about 10 times downstream - sometimes up to 20 times. Home is limited quite a lot, unless you are on a VDSL lnik with 10mbit uplink ;)

Comment: How I said: It's just for practice. :P it's not for real. I also would use a hoster.

Comment: There is no practice on a more visitors shop. As long as you only are one person (i.e. practice) the bandwidth is irrelevant. The moent it is real, the question is irrelevant ;)